# iOS mobile app that launches webapp - any problems getting it approved into app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-applications, app-store

I know that apple made the app store to, among other things, discourage web apps and control an unfair 30% cut of app transactions. Luckily for me, my rev comes from companies that are listed on the app, not users.

However, I want an app that does nothing but immediately open default browser and navigate to my webapp page. There is not even intermediary screen - See app icon/name on phone desktop, click, browser with webapp url launches.

Will this have problems getting approved by apple? If so what are the issues that I need to circumvent/overcome, and suggestions to do so? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the point of that? Can't you just build the web app and then tell your users to pin it to their homescreen? Seems like you save around 99 dollars that way

Comment: you really dont understand advertising do you @shadesandcolour

Comment: Do enlighten us. If someone advertises "try our iPhone app" and all it does is open Safari, I'm going to consider it false advertising and probably be soured on your stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Store Review Guidelines, 2.12:

> Apps that are not very useful, **are simply web sites bundled as apps**, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

You can essentially do this using the `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` and `apple-touch-icon` attributes supported by Safari, and you'll save the $99 fee.

Comment: Also, Apple didn't make the App Store to discourage web apps. iPhone 1 launched with no App Store, and Jobs heavily pushed web apps, even stating that they were so good there was little need for native apps.

Comment: he said that, then created the app store. @ceejayoz

Comment: Yes, because *developers* demanded more than web apps could offer - deeper device interactions, OpenGL graphics, etc. Good luck coding something like the Modern Warfare 3 iOS game as a web app.